# ls how to sort dotfiles first when using the -X option

Tags: shell, ls

Basically title. I want `ls` to sort by extension so I'm using the `-X` option, but I'd also like dotfiles to be shown first. I could use the `-v` option for that, but then `-X` no longer works.

How can I combine the two?

EDIT: my locale is

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: I don't think there is any way, except by running two `ls` commands like so: `ls -d1 .*; gls -X1`

Comment: You might be interested in looking into [`exa`](https://the.exa.website/) which labels itself as "a modern replacement for `ls`".  The sorting capabilities don't seem powerful enough yet for what you want, but there are some open feature requests about that you could chime in on.

Comment: What is the use case? Could you use the globs `.* *` together?

Comment: Could be a task for perl, python or ruby. Or as far as french keymap produce the output you want, maybe try to use french locale as a workaround (?!) `fr_FR.UTF-8`

Comment: @I0b0 How would I use that? `ls -AX .* *`'s output is weird.

Comment: @GillesQuenot I still get the same result even using `fr_FR.UTF-8` for every locale variable.